Should I be concerned about these cracks?
New home owner here and I’m sure there are a ton of these questions, but I’m getting paranoid about cracks under my windows. There was a non-offset foundation crack that we had inspected and it was determined that it wasn’t a huge cause for concern.
It keeps haunting me as I’m repairing these cracks around the house and I’m hoping these aren’t signs of bigger problems other than normal house settling.
These window cracks all look like they’ve made it to the baseboard.
Note: the first and last picture is shown after I’ve opened them up with a utility knife. The previous owner painted over them so I opened them up a bit and repaired with joint compound and tape.
Should I be concerned about a bigger issue?




What I see looks to be a normal crack (If one can call a crack normal). Due to settling and/or expansion and contraction of dissimilar materials.
Often with the seasonal climate change these cracks happen. When I lived in the NE of the US this was a common wintertime thing. Especially in older homes.
You may want to consider filling the cracks with acrylic painters caulk, rather than taping and mudding.  The caulk being somewhat flexible can help keep the crack from arearing again.

Thank you! I’m located in New England, Boston area. Really appreciate the advice, there are a couple of more smaller cracks that I need to fill that I’m going to use that tip for.

Note that acrylic caulk can also harden over time.  I might suggest a polyurethane sealant instead (e.g. OSI Quad), which can still be paintable.
